# Passing Object vs String as Method Parameter

Tags: c#

With the following code, I understand that getStringAgain(classOne.str1) is better than getAstring(classOne) because we only want to pass in what is necessary because of data hiding/encapsulation etc.

However, are there any memory benefits? Obviously the classOne object is larger than just a string, however since in both methods, we are passing in only a reference to an object, and therefore only the reference is copied to the stack, are they both just as efficient in terms of memory?

```
Class ClassOne()
{
    public string str1 = "string1";
    public string str2 = "string2";
}

Class ClassTwo()
{
    public ClassTwo()
    {
        ClassOne classOne = new ClassOne();
        string a = getAstring(classOne);
        string b = getStringAgain(classOne.str1)
    }

    private string getAstring(ClassOne classOne)
    {
        return classOne.str1;
    }

    private string getStringAgain(string str)
    {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Efficiency is the ratio of work done per unit cost. What do you mean by "efficient" in this case? What work is being done, and what cost are you measuring?

Answer (score 0):

string and ANY class are reference types

it means that the two functions take a reference to the managed heap where the actual data is held

nothing is copied.

if you know pointers its  basicly the same as passing a pointer.